# jQuery select an item using ID that is an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I've got a div element (checkbox) with an URL used like ID...

> id="http://www.mypage.com/page1"

then I got a variable in which I have the link

> var temp = "http://www.mypage.com/page1"

when i call this:

> $("#"+temp).trigger('click');

I got the error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #http://www.mypage.com/page1

Any ideas?

Comment: You must escape all special characters like `:` or `.`. Read more here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/. The moral here is that you should not use a url as an id.

Comment: you could have used a simpler id, if you want to pass in url, you can always pass it in with data attributes such as data-url="some_url"...!

Answer (score 0):

Aa @cristian mentioned above, you can't use a url as an id unless you remove all special chars form it. What you could do is, 1) remove spl chars from the ID, so that the ID is usable. 2) set jQuery data as your URL. Here is [my work around](http://jsfiddle.net/nq50uog4/1/) which works though it's a bit ugly.

```
var temp = "http://www.mypage.com/page1";
//Create an id from 'temp' removing all spl chars.
var tempID = temp.replace(/[^a-z0-9-_]+/gi, "");

//Find all IDs starting with http
$("[id^='http']").filter(function() {
    //Set data from the ID (URL)
    $(this).data("ele-path", this.id);
    //Change the id removing all spl chars.
    this.id = this.id.replace(/[^a-z0-9-_]+/gi, "");
});

$(document).on("click", "#" + tempID, function() {
    alert ("click");
    //Get the URL from data
    alert( $(this).data("elePath") );
});
```

Comment: that's work thanks. But i'm changing the id value from an url to a "normal" id.

Comment: That change is done by the script and you can continue to have the URL as ID if you really wanted to.